# onClick randomly not called while multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So basically my app can read out and process acceleration sensor values and display them in real time. This feature is what I call a measurement and by processing sensor values I mean calculating an FFT as well as storing new values in a temporary internal file.

For performance reasons I outsourced the processing part of a measurement to two separate threads, one for FFT calculation and one for storing the values in a temporary file. Thread priorities for both threads are set to `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`. The drawing of the sensor signal still happens in the main thread.

Then I have a button which stops the measurement. My problem is that this randomly fails with an increased chance to fail the longer the measurement is running. In these cases, when I click the stop button, the animation of it being pressed down is played but its onClick method is never called, resulting in the measurement to keep running. In that moment the entire UI gets unresponsive so that if I click another UI element, it animates that element as if I pressed it down but never released it and their onClick methods are also not called.

This did not happen before I implemented multithreading. At this point I appreciate any help regarding solutions for this problem, suggestions on how to debug it as well as opinions on how I implemented this measurement feature. I tried messing around with the Profiler in Android Studio but I couldn't extract relevant information from this. When it's stuck Logcat shows that I press and release the screen but nothing else.

**Measurement.java:**

```
public class Measurement {

    MainActivity activity;
    HandlerThread fftThread;
    HandlerThread fileWriterThread;
    Handler fftHandler;
    Handler fileWriterHandler;
    FourierTransform fft;
    double[] buffer;
    int bufferIndex;
    double[] spectrum;
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerationSensor;

    Measurement(MainActivity activity, int bufferSize) {
        this.activity = activity;
        fft = new FourierTransform(bufferSize);
        buffer = new double[bufferSize];
        bufferIndex = 0;
        spectrum = new double[bufferSize / 2];
        // init threads
        fftThread = new HandlerThread("FFTThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        fileWriterThread = new HandlerThread("FileWriterThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        // init sensor stuff
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerationSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    // call this to start the measurement
    void start() {
        // open the temporary file so we can write to it continuously
        try {
            outputStream = activity.openFileOutput("data.tmp", Context.MODE_APPEND);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // start the threads
        fftThread.start();
        fileWriterThread.start();
        // start their handlers
        fftHandler = new Handler(fftThread.getLooper());
        fileWriterHandler = new Handler(fileWriterThread.getLooper());
        // register to acceleration sensor to receive values
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerationSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    // call this to stop the measurement
    void stop() {
        // stop the threads without letting them finish their current task
        fftThread.quit();
        fileWriterThread.quit();
        // close the temporary file
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // this is called whenever the registered sensor has a new value
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double value = event.values[2];
        // write the new value to the buffer
        buffer[bufferIndex++] = value;
        if (bufferIndex == buffer.length)
            bufferIndex = 0;
        // draw the buffer on screen
        activity.drawGsvTime(buffer);
        // tell the fft thread what to do
        fftHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // perform a fourier transform on the buffer
                spectrum = fft.fft(buffer);
                // draw the result of the fourier transform
                activity.drawGsvFft(spectrum);
            }
        });
        // tell the filewriter thread what to do
        fileWriterHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // attempt to write the given data to the internal storage
                try {
                    String line = value + "\n";
                    outputStream.write(line.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Measurement measurement;
    GraphSurfaceView gsvTime;
    GraphSurfaceView gsvFft;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        initToolbar();
        // init the measurement
        measurement = new Measurement(this, 512);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // set the SurfaceViews
        gsvTime = findViewById(R.id.gsvTime);
        gsvFft = findViewById(R.id.gsvFft);
        // set an onClickListener to the stop button
        MaterialButton btnStop = findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // stop the measurement
                measurement.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // start the measurement
        measurement.start();
    }

    public void drawGsvTime(double[] data){
        gsvTime.drawGraph(data);
    }

    public void drawGsvFft(double[] data){
        gsvFft.drawGraph(data);
    }
}
```

**GraphSurfaceView.java**

```
public class GraphSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {

    Context context;
    double[] data;
    Paint paint;
    Path graph;
    float xStart, xEnd, yStart, yEnd, yMid; // helper variables for margins and offsets

    public GraphSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        this.context = context;
        paint = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1); // width of lines and texts
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); // don't fill drawn objects
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // line and text color
        graph = new Path();
        // calculate basic values
        int viewWidth = getWidth();
        int viewHeight = getHeight();
        xStart = viewWidth * 0.02f; // where to begin drawing along the x-axis
        xEnd = viewWidth - xStart; // where to stop drawing along the x-axis
        yStart = viewHeight * 0.08f; // where to begin drawing along the y-axis
        yEnd = viewHeight - yStart; // where to stop drawing along the y-axis
        yMid = viewHeight / 2f; // middle of yStart and yEnd
    }

    public void drawGraph(double[] data){
        this.data = data;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // set up some helper variables
        float maxAmp = (float) data[0]; // maximum amplitude of data
        for (double f : data) {
            if (Math.abs(f) > maxAmp)
                maxAmp = (float) Math.abs(f);
        }
        float yScalar = (yEnd - yStart) / (2 * maxAmp); // scalar for y values
        // draw diagram frame
        canvas.drawLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yStart, paint); // draw the upper line
        canvas.drawLine(xStart, yMid, xEnd, yMid, paint); // draw the middle line
        canvas.drawLine(xStart, yEnd, xEnd, yEnd, paint); // draw the lower line
        // calculate and draw sample values
        float x, y;
        graph.reset();
        graph.moveTo(xStart, yMid);
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            x = xStart + (j * (xEnd - xStart) / data.length);
            y = yMid + ((float) data[j] * yScalar);
            graph.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(graph, paint);
        // set text
        canvas.drawText(-maxAmp + " g", xStart, yStart - 4, paint); // draw upper Y value
        canvas.drawText(maxAmp + " g", xStart, yEnd + 12, paint); // draw lower Y value
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added the code to display the graphs on screen. I hope there are no copy pasta errors from my side.

**EDIT2:** So I managed to debug the MessageQueue (MQ) of every thread. While the measurement is running every MQ is empty. After my problem occurs the main thread's MQ is the only one with messages in it. [The first message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxrx.png) seems to be an empty message and to cause the unresponsiveness, but I'm not sure. The next messages always come in a pair of two with every click on the screen - "PerformClick" and "UnsetPressedState".

Comment: When the UI freezes, break into the debugger, then you can determine where the UI thread is stuck.

Comment: Debugging this is where I struggle the most since the UI isn't really freezing. The sensor signal is still drawn every frame and clickable items appear as pressed down when I click them, but nothing happens. Breaking into the debugger leads me to anywhere in `onSensorChanged` since the measurement just keeps running.

Comment: Please add your `drawGraph()` implementation and whatever code that is necessary to explain how the graph is rendered to the `View`.

Comment: Hmm, I can't spot the problem, right offhand. Initially I thought, "this is a UI thread Handler queue getting backed up", but can't see how. Unless the sensor samples are coming in so incredibly fast, or your `onSensorChanged()` implementation is slower than it looks. I would suggest temporarily commenting the `fft.fft(buffer)` call, and just displaying an empty `spectrum`, to see if that improves things. To be frank, you definitely have some bad threading practices, here, but in reference to the question at hand: Can't see the problem.

Comment: Another thing you can do is accelerate the device. If the movement doesn't show up on the graph, like, instantly -- you have a backed up UI thread Handler queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was the `invalidate()` call in my `drawGraph(double[] data)` implementation. Since I'm calling this from another thread I have to use `postInvalidate()` instead.